# Series expansion of ratio of modified bessel functions

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, bessel-functions

Let $I_{0}(z)$ and $I_{1}(z)$ be modified bessel functions of zero/first order (and first kind). How can I show that for the large value of $z$ it holds

$$\frac{I_{1}(z)}{I_{0}(z)}\sim 1 - \frac{1}{2z} - \frac{1}{8z^2} + O(z^{-3}).$$

I should use expansion of $I_{p}(z)$:

$$I_{p}(z)=\frac{e^{z}}{\sqrt{2\pi z}}\{1 - \frac{(4p^2-1)}{8z} +\frac{(4p^2-1)(4p^2-9)}{2(8z)^2} - \dots\}.$$

It's not hard to use expansion particularly for $p=0,1$ and then we get

$$\frac{I_{1}(z)}{I_{0}(z)}=\frac{1-\frac{3}{8z}-\frac{15}{2(8z)^2}-O(z^{-3})}{1+\frac{1}{8z}+\frac{9}{2(8z)^2}+O(z^{-3})}.$$

But how to work then with this ratio to finally get desired expansion?

Comment: Do a polynomial long division.

Comment: Tried that, but unfotunatelly didn't work for the right expression.

Comment: Simply divide the numerator by the denominator.

Comment: I ve tried that, but I still have a different coefficient with the desired expansion.

Comment: @stanly It's hard to tell what the issue is if you don't show your calculations.